# Why is my CosmosDb query not hitting any index?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a CosmosDb container from  which I'm trying to run an aggregated query which ends up with very high Request Charge. So I'm working to make it more efficient and noticed that no indexes were used.

The container has ~1.5 million documents, of which 700K related to `Year = 2023`. Partition key is `BusinessUnitId`

The query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT  c.BusinessUnitId, 
        c.OrganizationId, 
        c.Year,
        c.Month,
        SUM(c.CO2eValue) as CarbonEmissionValue,
        SUM(c.OriginalValue) as OriginalValue,
        c.EmissionSourceCategoryId,
        c.EmissionSourceCategory,
        c.EmissionSourceSubCategory
FROM c
WHERE c.Year = 2023
GROUP BY    c.BusinessUnitId,
            c.OrganizationId, 
            c.Year, 
            c.Month, 
            c.EmissionSourceCategoryId,
            c.EmissionSourceCategory,
            c.EmissionSourceSubCategory
```

The metrics for this query indicates that no indexes were used:

[image]

My index policy looks like this

```json
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ],
    "compositeIndexes": [
        [
            {
                "path": "/BusinessUnitId",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/OrganizationId",
                "order": "ascending"
            },            
            {
                "path": "/Year",
                "order": "ascending"
            },          
            {
                "path": "/Month",
                "order": "ascending"
            },                     
            {
                "path": "/EmissionSourceCategoryId",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/EmissionSourceCategory",
                "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
                "path": "/EmissionSourceSubCategory",
                "order": "ascending"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I have tried both with and without `compositeIndexes`, but the result is the same. I've also tried puttning `Year` first in the index list, but in either case `Index hit document count` comes out as **0**.

Thank you for any help

## Update

If I add the Partition key to the filter, I get Index hit 1.84, which seams low.

Comment: If you changed the index recently it might be due to the index taking a long time to build up again. If you simplify the query and just filter on the year. Does it then hit the index?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the grouping (and aggregations) the index hit equals the number of documents returned. I waited till the index was built

Answer (score 2):

I found this great video with Tim Sander which gave some great insight to index opimization. It was mentioned that we could look forward to see these features in the portal in the future, but until then, here is what you can do to get better understanding of your index utilization:

```cs
// Create a QueryRequestOptions and set the PopulateIndexMetrics to true
var queryRequestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions { PopulateIndexMetrics = true };

// Add the query request option to your query iterator:
using (var resultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(queryDefinition, requestOptions: queryRequestOptions))
{
   FeedResponse<T> response = await resultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
   data.AddRange(response);
   await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Result count: {response.Count}");
   await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"RequestCharge: {response.RequestCharge}");
   await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"IndexMetrics: {response.IndexMetrics}");
}
```

The result will come out something like this:

```bash
Result count: 30
RequestCharge: 3453,37
IndexMetrics:
Index Utilization Information
  Utilized Single Indexes
    Index Spec: /BusinessUnitId/?
    Index Impact Score: High
    ---
    Index Spec: /Year/?
    Index Impact Score: High
    ---
  Potential Single Indexes
  Utilized Composite Indexes
  Potential Composite Indexes
    Index Spec: /BusinessUnitId ASC, /Year ASC
    Index Impact Score: High
    ---
```

`Utilized Single Indexes` provides information about which index has been used, while the `Potential Composite Indexes` provides composite indexes you should consider.

Tim has also written a great post on the matter: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/query-performance-indexing-metrics/?ocid=AID754288&wt.mc_id=azfr-c9-scottha,CFID0714